# how to change mysql/mariadb 10.xx default port?

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb

To be precise I need to change mysql/mariadb 10.xx default port to port number 15501.

Through Internet I found that it could be changed from `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` containing a line `port=3306`, But in my cnf file there is no such line.

My `my.cnf` contents:

```
# The MariaDB configuration file
 #
 # The MariaDB/MySQL tools read configuration files in the following order:
 # 1. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf" (this file) to set global defaults,
 # 2. "/etc/mysql/conf.d/*.cnf" to set global options.
 # 3. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/*.cnf" to set MariaDB-only options.
 # 4. "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
 #
 # If the same option is defined multiple times, the last one will apply.
 #
 # One can use all long options that the program supports.
 # Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
 # --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.

 #
 # This group is read both both by the client and the server
 # use it for options that affect everything
 #
 [client-server]

 # Import all .cnf files from configuration directory
 !includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
 !includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
```

Don't know why But If I try `mysql -uroot -p -P[ANY_PORT IS ACCEPTED example 1829]` It connects to mariadb with any port number.

```
netstat -a | grep mysql
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     17787    /var/run/mysqld  /mysqld.sock

mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.23-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

I'm using debian 9

I would really appreciate if you tell me how to make mysql/mariadb listen to port 15501 number only.

Comment: In lines 4 to 7 of your config file is a list of places where "MariaDB/MySQL tools read configuration files" from. So look there. One of these will contain the port.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your first question (you want to run mariadb on a different port) is: add a port line in your `my.cnf` under the `mysqld` section such as:

```
[mysqld]
port=15501
```

And then restart your service. That should make your mariadb listen on 15501 instead of 3306.

About the second part... My guess is you didn't specify a hostname, so it defaulted to localhost and local socket connection in /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock, ignoring port parameter you gave, since local socket uses no port.

Comment: tried but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

The mysql-command is using a socket file for the connection to your local mariadb-server. You can see which port is open for mysql-connections by using netstat:

```
netstat -tulpen | grep mysql
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      104        1511        954/mysqld
```

For example you can search your config-files for the default port and change the port at this line to 15501:

```
$ find /etc/mysql/ -name "*.cnf" -exec grep -nHR '3306' {} \;
/etc/mysql/my.cnf:20:port               = 3306
/etc/mysql/my.cnf:38:port               = 3306
```

Comment: @apansiv Okay first of all I'm so sorry for my late reply, anyway I did found `port = 3306` at `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf` It still opens connection with any port